# How do I edit a usercontrol's subcontrol template in xaml when adding the usercontrol to a window?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a user control that contains a listview.  In the windows where I use this usercontrol, I want to be able to do something like what is shown below where I set the template for a control within the user control.

```
<ct:AutoCompleteComboBox 
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedCountry}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CountryList}" >
        <ct:AutoCompleteComboBox.DropDownList >

            <ListView 
                Background="Blue"
                MinWidth="150" 
                MaxHeight="200">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header=" Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  >
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Desc" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"  >
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </ct:AutoCompleteComboBox.DropDownList>
    </ct:AutoCompleteComboBox>
```

How do I go about doing this?  I found that if I made AutoCompleteComboBox.DropDownList a dependency property, then the code would compile.  However, this DropDownList property is not actually added to my control (it is added to the parent container of ct:AutoCompleteComboBox).

Any idea of the proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind subcontrol's property you want to be available outside to the property you created in the container control.

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was hoping for but it seems to solve this issue.  Thanks.  For anyone wanting more details, all I did was add a property in my usercontrol codebehind and had it get  myListView.View and set the myListView.View.  Then I was able to set the View via xaml from my main window by using <ct:AutoCompleteComboBox><ct:AutoCompleteComboBox.View ><GridView>...</GridView></ct:AutoCompleteComboBox.View ></ct:AutoCompleteComboBox>

Comment: Your solution is simpler and it is usually the way it is done in WinForms, but using dependency properties has some advantages. First and foremost, you'll be able to use bindings and animation with this property. Second, you'll be able to set the property within style. All this won't work with simple properties.